# Can you submit a job to HDInsight without going through WebHCat (Templeton)?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight

I am working with an existing tool that submits MapReduce jobs and would prefer to not have to change it to submit jobs via the REST API (WebHCat / Templeton) - is anyone aware of a way to do this?  Maybe a way to expose the MapReduce service to the server I'd like to submit the jobs from?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what tool you are currently using, and the api it uses to submit jobs. There are ways to avoid using templeton, but depending on the method, it may be as much work to avoid it as to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has released HDInsight .NET SDK.  See http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/submit-hadoop-jobs-programmatically/